# pre tags output required with different colour but with same alignment

Tags: html

I am trying to display a complete program code using the pre tags. The idea is to display the lines with different colours The issue here I am facing is in explorer I am getting the code as it was written originally but each line indentation is not correct
for eg:

```
fn(){
    int i=0;
    while (i<n)
    {
        printf("this is test");
    }
}
```

displayed with wrong indentation

```
    fn(){
    int i=0;
    while (i<n)
    {
    printf("this is test");
    }
}
```

and in some other computer in both IE or mozilla it is displayed 
 with extra line spacing

```
<html><head><style type="text/css">span.nonexec {color:red;font-family:"Cambria Math";line-height:inherit;font-size:small;}span.exec {color:green;font-family:"Cambria Math";line-height:inherit;font-size:small;}pre { white-space: pre-wrap; white-space: -moz-pre-wrap !important; white-space: -pre-wrap; white-space: -o-pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word;class="notranslate";}</style></head><body><pre><span class ="exec">fn(){     </span><span class ="nonexec">int i=0;     </span><span class ="exec">while (i<n)     {         </span><span class ="nonexec">printf("this is test");     } }</span></pre></body></html>
```

Can someone help me how to modify it so that I can have the code in the same format

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Don't use block elements for the different colours in your pre element. Use `span`s or the like. Although `pre` is supposed to act the same on different browsers, the effect of, for instance, a `h1` in a `pre` is, let's say, iffy.

Also, `class` is not a CSS property, you should remove those.

Comment: @Lister after adding the span the indentation issue fine now but still the extra line spacing in higher IE version or other browser it still exists Is there any way to rectify that. One more thing how doeas the inline CSS differ from what I have provided in the given code Updating the code with the new one as per your suggestions

Comment: Well, I don't have IE9, but it looks fine in IE8. At least, when I change it so that it looks how I think you want it to look... http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/ggRHs/ - Otherwise, show me a screenshot of what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Lister I had blocks of code to be represented so after adding div now the output is correct in IE but again in firefox it has multiple line spacing

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is not simple enough to achieve by simple html tags...

There are some apis who provide support to display code in your html with colors and indentions..

[Try This](http://qbnz.com/highlighter/)